# ListView with checkboxes

Tags: wpf, events, binding, mvvm, checkbox

I have a list of items displayed as a ListBox.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfSomeItems}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsReceived}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Now there is 2 user cases I need to implement:

1) When user mark an Item as received (the CheckBox get checked) I need to update the item. How should I bind the checked event to ICommand in my ViewModel?

2) When user tries to remove received flag (un-checks the checkBox) a pop up should be provided with an option to cancel the operation (if someone clicked the checkBox by accident) or to provide a note for a reason. That note along with the Item that been unchecked should be sent to different ICommand in VM.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
My viewModel do implements INoftiyPropertyChanged but I do not have property for the single item. The property is nested in complex class: something like Account.Holders[x].Requirements[y].IsReceived.

Comment: Regarding question 1 you don't have to use an ICommand. When the user checks the CheckBox the property Set method is called in the VM.

Comment: @jpsstavares - The property is nested in complex class: something like Account.Holders[x].Requirements[y].IsReceived. I would better execute a command than traverse the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why just not bind a command which should be exposed by ViewModel:

```xml
<CheckBox 
     Command="{Binding ReceivedStatusChangedCommand}"
     CommandParameter="{Binding ...IsReceived}"
/>
```

Then in command handler you can analyze passed in value of the `IsReceived` as command parameter.

Comment: I would like to see a solution that covers both user cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel should implement INoftiyPropertyChanged.  Just listen to the PropertyChanged event and respond to it.

**Edit**

Based on the structure of your ViewModel, if Account needs to respond the a Requirement, it might be best to use something like Prism's EventAggregator or MVVM Light's Messenger.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're binding to an `IsChecked` property in your object, you can simply listen to the `PropertyChanged` event for that object and call whatever method you need when it changes.

For example,

```cs
// Wireup CollectionChanged in Constructor
public MyVMConstructor()
{
    ListOfSomeItems = new List<SomeItem>();
    ListOfSomeItems.CollectionChanged += ListOfSomeItems_CollectionChanged;
}

// In CollectionChanged event, wire up PropertyChanged event on items
void ListOfSomeItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach(SomeItem item in e.NewItems)
            item.PropertyChanged += SomeItem_PropertyChanged;
    }
    if (e.OldItems != null)
    {
        foreach(SomeItem item in e.OldItems)
            item.PropertyChanged -= SomeItem_PropertyChanged;
    }
}

// In PropertyChanged, if property was IsReceived then verify and update
void SomeItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsReceived")
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            var item = sender as SomeItem;
            UpdateSomeItem(item.Id, item.IsReceived);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

MVVM solution would be:

1. Since bindings are two way you don't need to do anything to have your object updated from UI. But if you want your UI to be updated on changes in model, your model classes need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`
2. I imagine this would be done in `IsReceived` setter. Add two fields to your model class.

---

```
public string ValidationError
{ get; set; }

public bool HasValidationError
{ get; set; }
```

---

Then create a PopUp with error which is hidden by default. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your class, and bind PopUp visibility to `HasValidationError`, and message in inner `TextBlock` to `ValidationError`.

Comment: Is there something specific to that case that this wouldn't still apply? Same logic should be viable. If there's something that makes this very complicated you should think about creating ViewModel that would do any calculations or hierarchy traversals needed, and which is friendly to bind to.